# Maven Build failure in command prompt but getting build in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I am using `mvn clean` command from the command prompt and build is failing.

```
Downloading: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean- 
plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] ABC ......................................... FAILURE [  2.226 s]
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Total time: 3.098 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-16T15:10:36+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/153M
 [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of 
its 
 dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
 org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer 
artifact 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Received fatal alert: 
protocol_version - 
> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

But when I am using `mvn clean` command from inside of eclipse it is building successfully.

```
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---
Downloading: 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean- 
plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
Downloaded: 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean- 
plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom (5 KB at 5.2 KB/sec)
-------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] Total time: 4.387s
```

The difference i am able to see is that , in command prompt it is trying to download maven-clean-plugin-2.5 whereas from eclipse it is successfully downloading 2.4.1

But I need to run through 2.5 only .
Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant section of your `pom.xml`

Comment: Do you have proxy?

Comment: <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>  @RobAu

Comment: Dont know much about proxy. But I am on Company network @SasikumarMurugesan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know did you install maven globally. You can try to install maven globally. follow the steps.

1. Download maven from [maven download link](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. Create or export M2_HOME="MAVEN ROOT LOCATION". Ex. : **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\apache-maven-3.5.2**
3. Create or export MAVEN bin folder location to PATH variable. For example: **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\apache-maven-3.5.2\bin**
4. Open terminal or cmd and run **mvn --version** to confirm maven is installed or not.

You can use this same as with Eclipse. 
Then go to eclipse. and setup project.follow this steps

1. Import existing maven project or create a maven project
2. Goto project explorer and Right click on your pom.xml
3. then select Run As maven install.
4. and then what you want.
   Hope it will serve your purpose. You can download a [sample spring boot project](https://start.spring.io/) .

Or you can run a maven project from terminal or cmd. Just goto project root folder and then run a maven task like maven clean install . Happy Coding :)

[image]

Comment: all the steps are  already done. seems that bcoz I am on Company network, Maven is not able to connect to internet